# I can't see my partitions to install ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, partitioning, windows-7

I want to install `Ubuntu 12.04` on my PC. It already has Windows 7 on it. I wanna use both as a dual boot PC. My `HDD` is `1TB` & it has 4 partitions in Windows. But when I try to install Ubuntu I cant see those partitions. I can only see the whole `HDD` as a single partition. How can i fix it? Please help.

Comment: What is your disk configuration `basic` or `dynamic`. You can get this information by running `discmgmt.msc` in windows. Ubuntu can't be installed in dynamic disk

Comment: You can not install more than one basic partitions either. Just to note.

Answer (score 1):

Chances are you have one of two problems:

- **Leftover RAID data** -- This can usually be fixed by typing `sudo dmraid -E -r /dev/sda` at a Linux shell prompt, changing `/dev/sda` to the device filename, if it's not `/dev/sda`.
- **A damaged partition table** -- Many problems with MBR partition tables can be fixed with my [FixParts](http://www.rodsbooks.com/fixparts/) program; see its documentation for details. You'll probably need to run the Windows version or run it from an emergency disc like [Parted Magic](http://partedmagic.com/doku.php), though.

Comment: I dont wish to be rude- but your windows fixparts program doesn't seem very intuitive. I had downloaded the .exe and when I enter (what I think is) a device name it just comes up with a message and closes before I get a chance to read/do anything....

Comment: Then [RTFM.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/fixparts/) It's very well-documented.